# Python remember serial connection from another def

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

i created module which 1st connects to arduino with serial module like this `name=clockK('/dev/ttyACM0','9600')` and send data to arduino with command `name.send('4')`.

But when i'm sending data to arduino, it doesn't use earlier created "name".
Here is my code of clockK.py:

```
import datetime
import time
import serial
import os,sys,string
class clockK:
    def __init__(self, device, baund):
        try:
            self.device = device
            self.baund = baund
            self.naame=serial.Serial(device,baund).write('0')
        except:
            raise SerialNotResponding("Serial " + self.device + " is not responding!")
    def send(self, what):
        try:
            self.naame.write(what)
            return "Sent!: " + what
        except:
            raise ErrorSend("Can't send!")
    def who(self):
        return "You are communicating with: " + self.device + " at " + self.baund

class SerialNotResponding(Exception):
    pass
class ErrorSend(Exception):
    pass
```

So my question is how to "remember" serial define from **init** in def send?

A sample program with this module:

```
from clockK import *

a=clockK('device','speed')
a.send('1')
```

Answer (score 0):

In **init** open port like this

```
self.ser = serial.Serial()
self.ser.baundrate = baund
self.ser.open()
```

And send data like this

```
self.ser.write(what)
```